# If $|f(z)|\le |f(z^2)|$ then prove that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Bbb D$ be the open unit disc and $f:\Bbb D\to\Bbb C$ be an analytic function such that $|f(z)|\le |f(z^2)|$, for all $z\in\Bbb D$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Here is my **proof:** 
 For any $0<r<1$, consider the closed disc $B=\{z\in \Bbb D:|z|\le r\}$. Then the given condition implies that $|f(z)|\le |f(z^{2^n})|$, for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and for $z\in B$. Since for $z\in B$, $|z^{2^n}|\le r^{2^n}\to 0\implies z^{2^n}\to 0$. So by continuity, $|f(z)|\le |f(0)|$, for all $z\in B$. So by the Maximum modulus theorem, $f$ is constant on $B$. By the uniqueness theorem, $f$ is constant on $\Bbb D$. Is this correct? Let me know if there is any fallacy.

Comment: @Hetebrij It's probably safe to assume that this thing is supposed to be holomorphic.

Comment: Yes. $f$ is given to be analytic. Is then the proof ok?

Comment: I'm reading it now.. I think the hypothesis implies that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z^{2n})|$ not $|f(z)|\leq |f(z^{n})|$, but it doesn't affect your proof. Seems right otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's right. Thanks.

Comment: @Blake Should it instead be $z^{2^n}$? $$|f(z)| \le |f(z^2)| \le |f((z^2)^2)| = |f(z^4)| \le |f((z^4)^2)| = |f(z^8)| \le \ldots.$$

Comment: @Cameron Williams Ah yes that's right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The proof is correct, expect for 2 small points.
First, the Maximum Modulus Theorem as stated in Complex Analysis II of Stein and Shakarchi is about a function defined on a open set, such as $\mathbb{D}$, and in $\mathbb{D}$ we still have $z^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$, so there is no need to go to a smaller ball, unless your version is stated for functions from closed balls.
Second, the given condition implies $|f(z)| \le |f(z^{(2^n)})| $ instead of $|f(z)| \le |f(z^n)|$ for all $n$.